# Macbook power supply problems

Tags: mac, power-supply, macbook

I have just ordered my first Macbook but am worried because I have heard of lots of people having their powersupplye going bad even when plugged into a powerguard and surge protector.

We live in Papua New Guinea where the power is 240volts and there can be lots of outages and fluctuations.  It seems like other laptops don't have their power supplies going bad.

Any ideas on how to protect the power supply?

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a reliable, robust voltage stabilizer between all my electronic equipments and the mains supply. It works great. I have used a number of different laptops over the years, including a white MacBook for the past one year, and have not had any issues with batteries going bad due to fluctuations in voltage levels -- of which, we have a lot over here.

Comment: People here have been using surge protectors and powerguards and still have had many powersupplies go bad

Comment: I don't know what else to suggest to you -- perhaps a couple of voltage stabilizes lined up one after another. We see a lot of power outages throughout the year here; during summers, the voltages tend to fall quite low, then go back up, fall low, etc. Stabilizers have worked well for me.